# Spring Security: sequanece of antMatcher not working as expected

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have REST APIs and I wish to secure them using Spring Security -

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        http?.authorizeRequests()
                ?.antMatchers("/podcast/**")?.hasRole("admin")
                ?.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/podcast/details/**")?.permitAll()
                ?.antMatchers("/")?.permitAll()
                ?.and()
                ?.formLogin()
    }
```

`?.antMatchers("/podcast/**")?.hasRole("admin")` is working but,
`?.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/podcast/details/**")?.permitAll()` gets completely ignored when I'm trying to hit `http://localhost:8080/podcast/details/all` API.

However, when I reverse the pattenr checks like this -

```
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
        http?.authorizeRequests()
                ?.antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/podcast/details/**")?.permitAll()
                ?.antMatchers("/podcast/**")?.hasRole("admin")
                ?.antMatchers("/")?.permitAll()
                ?.and()
                ?.formLogin()
    }
```

It works as expected.

I was of belief that the strictest pattern has to be first but the above case is proving otherwise. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say stricter pattern first, it is not about the permission. It is about which url patterns are more specific.
So `/podcast/details/**` is more specific than `/podcast/**`

I.e when you receive request  `/podcast/details/123`, it will go for url matching in the order you defined. So if you put `/podcast/**` as first, it will match it and it does not check the rest